# js wait in loops untill content loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with waiting until ajax is complete.

I need to go through all options of select lists(there are 5 lists).
After clicking an option in "Select1", it loads(or refreshes) "Select2" control, where I click some option and it loads "Select3", and so on...

So, I need to wait in the loops until the necessary content is loaded.

I've read about `$.when`, but I don't know what ajax requests are launched, and can't do like this:

```
var myAjax = $.ajax({ ... });
$.when(myAjax).then(...);
```

Also, I've seen `ajaxSuccess`/`ajaxStop`, but don't know how to make it work in my case.

Here is my code

```js
$('selector1').each(function (i, v1) {
    $(v1).mouseup(); // launch loading
    // need to wait till 'selector2' elements load
    $('selector2').each(function (i, v2) {
        $(v2).mouseup(); // launch
        // .. wait ..
        $('selector3').each(function (i, v3) {
            $(v3).mouseup(); // launch
            // .. wait ..
            $('selector4').each(function (i, v4) {
                 $(v4).mouseup(); // launch
                 // .. wait ..
                 $('selector5').each(function (i, v5) {
                     // ... do something
                 });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**Update.**

I need to grab information about wheels from a website(not mine), using this javascript from console, so these ajax requests are not written by me and I don't know from where are they loaded, they just fire, when I click an option with js. And I need to wait till they complete.

I logged url of ajax requests using ajaxSuccess, they are:

```
/netcat/podbor.php?key=113224Select1
/netcat/podbor.php?key=113224Select2
/netcat/podbor.php?key=113224Select3
/netcat/podbor.php?key=113224Select4
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML and also the details from where the dropdown values are loaded..

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `done` setting for your ajax request. That is, instead of just calling the Ajax request, have a .done(function()) attached.

It would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // arguments of the ajax request
    }).done(function() {
        //things to do once the ajax request is finished
});
```

You can see a few examples on [the jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Thanks for answering. There is an update of my question, the thing is, that I do not write this ajax request, cause I use js to get info from a website

Answer (score 0):

Vemonus answer is just what you need however, an option to use when waiting on multiple ajax requests to complete is [jQuery's when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). Like so:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({}),

    $.ajax({})

).then(function() {
    // code after ajax requests complete
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've made an update to clear the situation. 
Unfortunately as I mentioned above, I can't do like this, I use javascript to grab information from website.